# Couldn't import functions from files in the same directory

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRyqG.png)I am trying to import a function that I created from a file in the same directory, but the python console always reports the import error, saying that no module have been found. I am 100% sure that I did not misspell the name of the file nor the function name, it just keeps saying that module name isn't found. Some say that it has to do with the **init**.py file but there's tons of files named **init**.py and I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with them. I am using PyCharm and I stored my files in the default project directory. Can somebody help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLQet.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkcCU.png)

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with what files you have, which folders they are in, and/or exactly what code you wrote to try to import them; but I can't see *any* of these things, so there is no way I could possibly tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I just added an image link to my post. As you can see the init.py file is there, but it's empty, let me know if you need to see what's inside the venv folder.

Comment: My answer wasn't close enough to explain anything. So one of the problem is that your module name must not be separated by spaces. Second I too tried to create a similar directory and found out I too got an error. Strangely I never experienced it in django.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I put the exact same code into another file, but this time I renamed the file so that the file name does not contain spaces. Then I tried importing the same function once again and it worked! Seems like a space could make a huge difference in python. Anyway thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Ok that means I  have an answer that can work. Well I personally got https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent and thus I deleted my answer. Remember file name must not contain spaces. I still need to read on fixing that error. Thanks for increasing my knowledge.